# Webmail access through PHP

Tags: php, cpanel, pop3, webmail

I have Cpanel and domain. I can create email account by going to the email account option in Cpanel. My question is how can I create an email account in Cpanel from a php web application?
I want a proper guide to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/create-e-mail-accounts-e-mail-forwarding-without-logging-c-panel-dynamic-way-217551.html

Comment: That was not sufficient enough. Can you refer me to some other resources?

Comment: Try this, it was linked from that page and looks like it should work: http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/php-script-generating-forwarders-programmatically-115569.html The second post has a way to create a forwarder using XML.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you have access to the server (VPS). Please correct me if I am wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check it out.I hope it will help you what you want.

http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-create-email-account.php

Comment: Great solution! How would you make that more secure though?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Its for gmail account.Configure for your account:

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'username@gmail.com';
$password = 'password here';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' .   imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
   if($emails) {

/* begin output var */
$output = '';

/* put the newest emails on top */
rsort($emails);

/* for every email... */
foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

    /* output the email header information */
    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
}

echo $output;
} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

I think this will help you.Thanks.razin223

Comment: Question was how to create an email account with PHP, not view an email account's mail. Very cool script though :)